# How to override grid-template-columns property in child div

Tags: css

How to override grid-template-columns property in child div

I have parent div where i used grid-template-columns and then 3 child div. I want first two div to be in same row with 50% width and third div should talk full width. So i am trying to
overwrite grid-template-columns property in 3rd div with another CSS class but it is not overriding the property for 3 div.

Below is my code.

Please confirm how can i make 3rd child div to take full width.

```css
.outer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr));
  row-gap: 24px;
  width: unset;
  align-self: unset;
}

.full {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, minmax(0, 1fr));
}

.inner {
  height: 220px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: static;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"> this is first div
  </div>

  <div class="inner"> this is second div
  </div>

  <div class="inner full"> this is third div this is third div this is third div this is third div this is third div this is third div this is third div this is third div
  </div>
</div>
```